# Displaying m:n relationship in database

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, phpmyadmin

how do you construct mysql command to display data with m:n relationship?

i can use join to display a 1:n relationship, but when constructing m:n relationship, another table is created and when i try to do the same it, it only show one table plus the relationship table.

For example, I have :

**table A:**

- `A_id`
- `A_data`

**table B:**

- `B_id`
- `B_data`

**table C:**

- `A_A_id`
- `B_B_id`

I can display the table such that i have

```
A_id | A_data | A_A_id | B_B_id
```

with some data.

but the format that i want is

```
A_id | A_data | B_id | B_data
```

where `A_id` corresponds to `B_id` in table C.
I'm doing this through foreign key reference, with InnoDB engine of MySQL.

thanks

Comment: FIRST format the question please...

Comment: Wouldn't a simple INNER JOIN among the 3 tables suffice? SELECT A.A_id, A.A_data, B.B_id, B.B_data FROM C JOIN B ON C.B_B_id = B.B_id JOIN A ON C.A_A_id = A.A_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want C to be the base table for the query (ie basically take table C and add in the corresponding `_data` rows), you can use:

```
SELECT A.A_id, A.A_data, B.B_id, B.B_data
FROM C
LEFT JOIN A ON A.A_id = C.A_A_id
LEFT JOIN B ON B.B_id = C.B_B_id
```

This takes the table C and `JOIN`s it to the other two tables, using C as the base table (because of the `LEFT JOIN`). If there are rows in C that don't exist in A or B, you'll just get a corresponding NULL for the `_data` field.

You might want to look at the various joins [(INNER, LEFT, RIGHT,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) to see what behaviour you want.

For example you may want all ids that exist in table A to be shown, even if they aren't in C (and just display a NULL for the corresponding B columns), etc.

Comment: thank you. it works well enough for pulling out information that i need. I'll look into it